# inverse of a function which contain logarithm

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=2^{x}(x-1) $is a bijective function . What will be the inverse of $f$ ?
For this we want to find another function $g$ with composition of both give identity function. So I want to separate $x$ and $y$. How can we do this? Is there any other ways to find inverse ?

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$?  Unless this information is given, the idea of "bijective" is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Since you look at the inverse function of $f(x)=2^{x}(x-1)$ you search for $x=g(y)$ such that $y=2^x(x-1)$.

For this specific case, only Lambert function provides an explicit answer and the result is given by $$x=1+\frac{W\left(\frac{1}{2} y \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}$$

In practice, any equation of the form $$a+b x+c \log(d+ex)=0$$ has a explicit solution in terms of Lambert function.

Comment: how can we start the proof..?

Comment: Start writing $y=2~2^{x-1}(x-1)$ and use the definition of $z=W(z) e^{W(z)}$